# Android - Scrolling through ListView leads to Out of Bounds Exception

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm working on an application that primarily consists of a list view. It's backed up by my own custom array adapter whose size changes every 5 seconds. If I scroll through the list view as the array adapter changes from a greater size to a lesser size, I get an out of bounds exception. It makes sense to me why this occurs (since I'm scrolling at a position beyond the new array size), but I was wondering if there was a good way to debug it. I can't seem to come to a clear conclusion, and I was wondering if I could get some help.

I update the adapter using the following asyncTask...

```
public class myTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            while(isRunning){
                myData.clear();
                getData();
                publishProgress();
                SystemClock.sleep(5000);
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void...progress){
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }     
}
```

`myData` is the ArrayList that supports `listAdapter` and `getData()` is the function that populates `myData` with the relevant info that will eventually be displayed in my list view.

Is there a good way to tackle this problem?

Regards

Comment: Do you have onScroll listener?

Comment: Why are you scrolling to a position that the array doesn't have? The adapter should only return the elements that you DO have, right?

Comment: @Nikola, I don't have onScroll listener, and I was just thinking that I will need to implement that in order to prevent the exception. dmon, Therein lies my problem, hehe. If the adapter changes from a larger size to a smaller size at a moment I'm scrolling at a position greater than the smaller size, that's when I get the out of bounds exception.

Comment: Hmmm.... position of the items is always - the first visible position..

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a custom adapter?

Perhaps in your getViewTypeCount() and getItemViewType(int position) it is going out of bounds there. The view type count should be from (0, n] but the item view type should be [0, n).

E.g. view type count should be 2

But the view types should be 0 and 1, not 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2):

try to override the getCount() function of the adapter class:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
return [list that contains data].size();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea why my listview was going out of bounds. It worked fine at all times except when I was refreshing for searching. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried resetting the user to either the top of the list or as close as possible when the list changed sizes?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, maybe is not the answer for the question, but having that infinite loop seems for me that is not the correct way, even if it´s an async task.

I would try to use the an AlarmManager or a Timer.

With that said, seems what you have is a race condition, take into account that it´s not immediately when you ask for data, or a specific position and rebuild the views.

Cheers,
Francisco.

Comment: Thanks, Francisco. I took your advice and tried implementing the use of a Timer, but I still get that same error. There is a race condition going on, and I thought a Timer would solve it. Nevertheless, it's still rarely occurring.